# newtxmath and tikz in collision

Tags: fonts, tikz-trees

When I try to draw a Feynman diagram with superscripts, if I use newtxmath, the superscripts on the particles (like `\mu^{-}`) won't show. Here's the mwe:

```
%&latex
\documentclass[twocolumn,prc,floats,amsmath,amssymb,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib,11pt]{revtex4-1}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    photon/.style={decorate, decoration={snake}, draw=black},
    electron/.style={draw=black, postaction={decorate},
        decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with {\arrow[draw=black]{>}}}},
    gluon/.style={decorate, draw=magenta,
        decoration={coil,amplitude=4pt, segment length=5pt}} 
}
\newcolumntype{y}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[
        thick,
        % Set the overall layout of the tree
        level/.style={level distance=1.5cm},
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.6cm},
        level 3/.style={sibling distance=2cm}
    ]
    \coordinate
             child[grow=right, level distance=0pt] {
        child  {
            child {
                child {
                    node {$\overline{\nu}_e$}
                    edge from parent [electron]
                }
                child {
                    node {$e^{-}$}
                    edge from parent [electron]
                }
                node[above=15pt]{$W^{-}$}
                edge from parent [photon]
            }
            child {
                node {$\nu_\mu$}
                edge from parent [electron]
            }
            edge from parent [electron]
            node [below] {$\mu^{-}$}
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}






\end{document}
```

This one will make the diagram, but without superscripts :\ If I leave the newtxmath out, I'll have the superscripts on the diagram, but also the 'math text' is, well, not in tx font :| Any solution to this?

EDIT: Added log file (File list):

```
 *File List*
revtex4-1.cls    2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for 
documentation)
  aps4-1.rtx
aps11pt4-1.rtx
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
 amssymb.sty    2009/06/22 v3.00
amsfonts.sty    2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support
 amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
revsymb4-1.sty    2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for
 documentation)
 caption.sty    2012/02/19 v3.2f Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2012/01/12 v1.4b caption3 kernel (AR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   dvips.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
tgtermes.sty    2009/09/27 v1.2 TeX Gyre Termes as default roman family
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
newtxmath.sty    2012/11/19 v1.06
  binhex.tex
 xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
  ot1qtm.fd    2009/09/25 v1.2 font definition file for OT1/qtm
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
omlntxmi.fd    2012/03/22 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OML/ntxmi.
omsntxsy.fd    2012/11/14 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OMS/ntxsy.
omxntxex.fd    2012/04/18 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OMX/ntxex.
 untxexa.fd    2012/04/16 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxexa.
 untxsya.fd    2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsya.
 untxsyb.fd    2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsyb.
 untxmia.fd    2012/04/16 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxmia.
 untxsyc.fd    2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsyc.
 ***********
```

Comment: I get the superscripts with the very same code.

Comment: Even with the `\usepackage{newtxmath}`? :\ Weird, because in my code when I enable it, I don't have them, when I disable it, I get superscripts :\ For the exact same code...
http://i.imgur.com/aqQ5xRG.png

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using? Did you update it?

Comment: I'm using MikTeX 2.9 64-bit. I think it's up to date...

Comment: Can you try adding `\listfiles` at the beginning and showing the contents of the log file after `* File list *`?

Comment: Added to the original.

Comment: I have `newtxmath.sty 2013/02/10 v1.08`

Comment: How do I update it? I used miktex (TeXStudio) when I installed it...

Comment: Use the MiKTeX wizard, it shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: @dingo_d In case the upgrade solved the issue, can you either post that as an (accepted) answer and/or (flag to) close the question as too localized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, the upgrade solved my issue, I totally forgot to say it... Sorry :\